# jquery add data attribute while creating dynamic dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to add data attribute while creating custom dynamic dom elements

like  -

```
var div = $('#ajey');

  var text = "<div class='parent'>parent div";

  text +="<div class='child' data-child='true'>how do I add .data value for this div during on the fly dom creation?</div>";

  text += "</div>";

  div.html(text);
```

Fiddle here - [Demo](http://jsbin.com/lanotu/1/edit)

Here I have added `data-child` this works, but when someone inspect elements via developer tools this is visible.

Where as the if I add via jquery .data() the data is not visible in the developer console.

But I am not able to figure out how to add data via jquery when I am creating elements on the fly.

Comment: jquery's `.data` doesn't actually add DOM data attributes but rather keeps the attributes in JS land.

Comment: oh and how do I associate a dom's data attribute to be kept in the JS land ? while I am generating the dom element?

Comment: Honestly I would stay away from data attributes - if you're generating them you can push them into an array of objects and keep data related to them outside of your presentation layer. You can use `.attr` if you must: `$("<div ... />").attr("data-foo", "bar")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code and fiddle.

```
var div = $('#ajey');

      var text = "<div class='parent'>parent div";

      text +="<div class='child'>how do I add .data value for this div during on the fly dom creation?</div>";

      text += "</div>";


      div.html(text); 
div.find('.child').data('child', 'true'); //data-child attribute is added but will not show in DOM when user inspects element
console.log($('.child').data('child')); //you can see the value of data-child attribute in console to make it confirm that it is added.
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/v0qmbL5z/1/

Comment: In this case you add data attribute after as the element is located in DOM. This is not 'on the fly'.

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $('#ajey');

var text = "<div class='parent'>parent div";
text +="<div class='child' data-child='true'>how do I add .data value for this div during on the fly dom creation?</div>";
text += "</div>";

var parent = $(text);

parent.attr("data-foo", "bar");
parent.find('.child').attr("data-foo", "bar");

div.html( parent );
```

OR

```
var parent = $(text);

parent.data("foo", "bar");
parent.find('.child').data("foo", "bar");

div.html( parent );

console.log($('.parent').data('foo'));
console.log($('.parent').find('.child').data('foo'));
```

DEMO: [http://jsbin.com/necoqo/1/](http://jsbin.com/necoqo/1/edit?html,js,output)